# Could a space faring civilization extract valuable resources from a gas giant?

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, space-constructs, natural-resources, gas-giants

I have been developing an advanced civilization inhabiting a world orbiting a gas giant about 3 times the mass of jupiter, the conditions have already been tuned to allow life to develop over its surface to the point of giving rise to intelligent beings.

I have been wondering if it would be plausible that they started utilizing their gas giant as a source of advanced resources, such as helium-3, as they started becoming space farers.

With space farers I don't mean interstellar specie, but mainly starting to colonize their star system, building outposts on the other worlds and within the asteroid belt, think about 'The Expanse' but with most of the population being concentrated on the homeworld and no settlemnt being truly self sufficient. As for technology, again think like 'The Expanse' if only just a bit more advanced featuring quantum computers, nanotechnology, cybernetics, biotech, advanced robotics and AI.

To give you a better idea of the situation:

Gas giant mass: 3 times the mass of jupiter

Moon mass: 0.7 earths

Distance: 1002864 kms or 544000kms

Do you think it would be plausible that they'd have facilities extrating helium 3 and similar compounds from their gas giant? And in case it weren't, do you think they could ever do that with more advanced technology?

Comment: Take look at this one u may need it http://toughsf.blogspot.com/2017/09/low-earth-orbit-atmospheric-scoops.html  also google "orbit air scooping" there is some fresh spin on the topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**

However, unless you are considering ultra high tech and mega structures, it would be much much cheaper to mine the ice of the moons or rings for He3.

Mining off of the moons means you don't have to deal with with weather of the gas giant.

Comment: ShadoCat That is an excellent point yes, pheraps it would be better to save that for when they become interstellar. What if they tried to harness the energy of the storms though? I heard that they are extremely powerful in the gas giants, could they do that with interplanetary technology?

Comment: You also don't have to deal with the gravity of the gas giant which is the biggest problem

Comment: @JuimyTheHyena The trouble is that as Thorne mentioned, a Gas Giant's gravity well is so strong that any energy you got from the storms would be lost trying to export it out of the gravity well.  Also, I question how much energy you could get.  An Earth based windmill can get energy from the wind because it is anchored to the Earth.  There is nothing to anchor a generator to in a gas giant.  You can no doubt generate some energy that way just by being in a wind sheer area but probably not enough to offset the cost of the equipment.

Comment: ShadoCat  I see, but what if one were trying to harness the static electricity? Like through the use of lightning rods?

Comment: @JuimyTheHyena, lightning rods connected to what?  You can't ground anything except to the local electric potential.  Now it is possible to have very long wires that run from one zone that has potential X to a zone that has potential Y but how do you protect that wire?  All of this would be nice for a floating city in the upper atmosphere of the gas giant but the cost of exporting the energy off the gas giant will likely be more than the energy itself.

Comment: ShadoCat  How did I not think about that...you are correct.

Comment: I love science but I was an Economics major.  I think of science in the terms of costs and markets.

Comment: Quite weak answer for two major reasons. Easier is relative term and they are already at orbit of a gas giant and do they have usefull things near by isn't stated by op, so in the answer it is an assumption without reasoning behind it. Landing is not required with gas giants, this type of planets does not require landing for resource extraction. Considering that we have suitable technologies already it just a lack of what and how things can be done in such situation. He3 makes sense only for fusion and with Expanse tech level everything goes effortlessly, even we could have done that.

Comment: @JuimyTheHyena do you ahve fusion in your setting starting conditions or not, if you do - what use it has storm energies, ligthing rods - use reactors for energy, the other energh sources are just inferior in every aspect.

Comment: MolbOrg I don't think it would be possible to have an interplanetary civilization without fusion power, so yeah they do have fusion.

Comment: @MolbOrg I never said anything about landing (since a gas giant has nothing to land on).  I said that the Ice on moons will be easier to get to.  The energy cost of coming out of the gravity well of the gas giant is orders of magnitude higher than the energy cost of lifting from a moon.

Comment: You again think in therms of landing, meaning stopping orbiting around body(irrelevant what happens next - landing, floating, whatever)  indeed dropping orbit from 1e6km to 1e5km takes about 32 km/s(to start descent 10km/s is enough), leaving however, and heading to other places where ice bodies can be, takes about 10+km/s, also op states nothing about presense of those around this gas giant and it not expected as else they won't have habitable temperature on their planet, so best case those are like our Luna - dry as sole. So there not neccessarly even any win at all.

Comment: With gg, one can teleoperate equipment, it does straigthforward thing, it has constant inflow of reactive mass and fuel by doing so and the process is extreamly primitive, simple and its automation is like stealing candy from a kid, it easy. And caring about energy or reactive mass is pointless in this case as have constant inflow of reactive mass which is captured to extract fusion fuel from it which provides energy for operation and extra is sent home. Without fusion it about the same but just slower. Sure u can keep your opinion, it just that you really could improve u answer

Comment: Fundamentaly - yes answer - is a correct one, it just reasons are much different and I understand that something is better than nothing, and there isn't a queue of people jumping in to answer @JuimyTheHyena question, but you could put a bit more efforts in it, considering there enough q/a on the topic of extraction of resources from gas giants, here on wb, which can be linked or something. U expirienced user you should keep the standart, lol. Idk just saying, was just passing by

Comment: @MolbOrg, yes you can tele-operate the extraction of H3 from the gg.  However, it does no good until you get it to where it needs to be.  Thus, you have to get it out of the gravity well of the gg.  I never said that getting H3 from the GG was impossible.  I said that it was easier to get it from the moons.  None of your elaborate gg mining methods disprove that it is easier to get it from a moon.